How to enable 'sentence' and 'paragraph' in passage_boundary for BuildExcerpts
We are currently using Sphinx 2.1.9 and I would like to enable 'sentence' and 'paragraph' in passage_boundary for BuildExcerpts.
For now, we only have excerpts with words around like so:
" ...  and has spoken out against book bans and in favor of ... "
I tried to set index_sp to 1 in the index configuration and reindex but that does not change anything.

Its not clear what you trying to do. Your example excerpt doesn't have any sentence (or paragraph) boundaries in it anyway, so that excerpt wouldnt change using passage_boundary  setting.
